# laravel eloquent multiple where statement

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have used the following code for conditional where query. But I didnt get the result in foreach statement but if I use $member->first() I am getting the result. Is this the correct way to use conditional where in laravel?

```
$member = Member:query();
 if(!empty($param['activity'])){
                $member->where('activity', 'LIKE', $param['activity'] .'%');
            }
            if(!empty($param['MemberName'])){
                $member->where('MemberName', 'LIKE', $param['MemberName'] .'%');
            }
            if(!empty($param['Designation'])){
                $member->where('Designation', 'LIKE', $param['Designation'] .'%');
            }
    $member->take(100)->skip($offset)->get();
    foreach ($member as $arr)
            {
    ....
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is totally the right way to do it. However you're missing one little thing. `get()` will return the result *but* the `$member` will still be the query builder instance. What you need to do is assign the result to `$member`

```
$member = $member->take(100)->skip($offset)->get();
```